# Filter keys of the objects in a deeply nested JSON with jq

Tags: json, nested, jq, tree-traversal

Given the following input

```json
[
  {
    "k1":[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5,"f":6}],
    "k2":[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5,"f":6}]
  }
]
```

how should I proceed to obtain the following output?

```json
[
  {
    "k1":[{"a":1,"b":2}],
    "k2":[{"a":1,"b":2}]
  }
]
```

i.e. I have some objects deeply in the JSON, and I want to remove all keys in those nested objects except `"a"` and `"b"`, and keep the original JSON structure.

Note however that the original object might have dozens of keys, I only want to keep 2 or 3 of them.

For simple top-level operations I was able to select subsets of objects with `{a:.a, b:.b}` or `{a,b}` syntax, but in the nested context I don't know how to proceed and preserve the JSON structure.

In general, what is the best attitude to do operations on a deeply nested level, without altering the parent levels?

Answer (score 0):

In brief, `walk` is your friend.

(If it is not available in your jq, simply include its def in your jq program; the def can easily be found by googling: jq def walk)

Some variation of the following should solve the immediate problem:

```
walk( if type == "object" then {a,b} else . end )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `|=` operator to do what you want on nested levels.

There is also a fairly simple function you can use to pick specific paths out of json objects.

[This stackoverflow.com thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72745488/how-to-filter-object-containing-nested-keys-and-lists-to-specific-keys-with-jq) has a more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you:

```
map({ k1 : [(.k1[]|{a,b})], k2 : [(.k2[]|{a,b})] })
```

[test1](https://jqplay.org/s/9fHe4vETsqv)

or this:

```
[.[]|{ k1 : [(.k1[]|{a,b})], k2 : [(.k2[]|{a,b})] }]
```

[test2](https://jqplay.org/s/aUAB6l5Roi6)