# How to filter object containing nested keys and lists to specific keys with jq

Tags: jq

Suppose I have an object like:

```json
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": [
    {
      "d": 1,
      "e": 2
    },
    {
      "d": 2,
      "e": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

and I wish to extract only a set of keys (which are possibly nested), like `.a` and `.c[].d`, giving us the following output:

```json
{
  "a": 1,
  "c": [
    {
      "d": 1
    },
    {
      "d": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Giving credit where it is due: This question (and my attached answer) are based off [Zirak's](https://github.com/Zirak) [issue on the jq GitHub](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2062), partially answered by [itchyny](https://github.com/itchyny) & [pkoppstein](https://github.com/pkoppstein), then continued by me and [wader](https://github.com/wader), with a more complex use case which wasn't covered by their solutions.

Comment: Also, after writing this thread, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72369864/) question which seems to contain the answer suggested by wader, but was posted before my question on the GitHub issue - so credit is due there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two possible ways to do it:

1. Explicitly extracting the keys (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62467840/) question), e.g.:

```bash
$ jq '{a, c: .c[] | {d}}' test.json 
{
  "a": 1,
  "c": {
    "d": 1
  }
}
{
  "a": 1,
  "c": {
    "d": 2
  }
}
```

which works but can get ugly very quickly if you try to use it with long keys or deeply nested sub-objects.

Note that selecting paths that don't exist will result in `null`:

```bash
$ jq '{a, c: .c[] | {f}}' test.json                               
{
  "a": 1,
  "c": {
    "f": null
  }
}
{
  "a": 1,
  "c": {
    "f": null
  }
}
```

2. Implementing `pick` function to filter an object for specific keys:

```
def pick(paths):
  . as $root |
    reduce path(paths) as $path
      ({}; setpath($path; $root | getpath($path)));
```

Resulting in:

```bash
$ jq "$(cat query.jq)"' pick(.a, .c[].f, .c[].d)' test.json  
{
  "a": 1,
  "c": [
    {
      "f": null,
      "d": 1
    },
    {
      "f": null,
      "d": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

If we'd like non-existent paths to be omitted instead of set to `null`, we can add `haspath` function to check if a path exists inside an object like so:

```
def haspath($path):
  def h:
    . as [$json, $p]
    | (($p|length)==0) or
      ($json | (has($p[0]) and ( [getpath([$p[0]]), $p[1:] ] | h)));
  [., $path] | h;

def pick(paths):
  . as $root |
    reduce path(paths) as $path
      ({}; if $root|haspath($path) then . + setpath($path; $root | getpath($path)) else . end);
```

Resulting in:

```bash
$ jq "$(cat query_haspath.jq)"' pick(.a, .c[].f, .c[].d)' test.json 
{
  "a": 1,
  "c": [
    {
      "d": 1
    },
    {
      "d": 2
    }
  ]
}
```